# GWT: Suggest box with multiple words

Tags: gwt, autosuggest

I need to make suggestion TextBox where user can write some keywords ( to search across file archive with specified keywords ). But keywords can be entered sequentially with some delimiter.

for example: `keyword1; keyword2; key...`

I want to make it with GWT.

Please, tell me if you know some implementation examples (may be in JavaScript/jQuery) or how to make this.

TIA

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking for the [`SuggestBox`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html). But its default [`SuggestOracle`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestOracle.html) - [`MultiWordSuggestOracle`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MultiWordSuggestOracle.html) only allows one "suggestion" per box. So you want to write your own, custom `SuggestOracle`. [MutipleSuggestBox](http://ljvjonok.blogspot.com/2008/10/gwt-suggestbox-how-to-make-multiple.html) is a basic/simple implementation that should get you started. For some extra insight and more eye-candy, please see the [Facebook-style Autocomplete with GWT](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/creating_a_facebook_style_autocomplete) article.