# Interactive Elements within a GWT widget

Tags: gwt, autocomplete, widget, interactive

I am planning on implementing a smart autocomplete-searchbar using GWT.

The user has to be able to enter a text, while suggestions are displayed below the searchbar. This functionality is easily implemented using GWT's SuggestBox widget. However, once the user selects one of the suggested words, that word should be displayed, if possible, within the searchbar as an interactive widget (so that it is not displayed as a simple string, but as a new widget containing the selected string within the searchbar) that can be clicked on to open a popup window containing more information and removed by clicking an "x" within the widget, for example. If this is not possible, the result could also be displayed somewhere next to the searchbar.

The user should be able to keep on typing and adding more elements to the searchbar. As a reference, it should pretty much work like the "Tags" bar when asking a question here on stackoverflow.

I have done quite a lot of research regarding this challenge but haven't really found any information suiting my needs, so I wanted to ask the stackoverflow community if anyone has done anything similar and could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's already discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666488/gwt-suggest-box-with-multiple-words).

On following site it's described how to handle it.
http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/creating_a_facebook_style_autocomplete